# rosjava errors on oneiric

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosjava, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to make the simple example from the rosjava page I am running into several problems. The first is that rosdep is complaining that it cannot install 'ant'. This seems to be a solved problem (see https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3783) but for some reason it is still a problem on my system.

Even when I make with a "rosmake --no-rosdep" I get problems with std_msgs for example:
check-gen-srv-skip:

gen-srv:

compile:
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/stephen/.ros/rosjava/build/actionlib_msgs
[javac] GoalStatusArray.java:9: package org.ros.message.std_msgs does not exist
[javac]   public org.ros.message.std_msgs.Header header = new org.ros.message.std_msgs.Header();

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30785/rosjava-errors-on-oneiric/) by [Steveb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2079/steveb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend to follow this tutorial:
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

---

Originally posted by [kurmis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1980/kurmis/) with karma: 51 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0